# How do you drop a permanent table that has multiple prefixes on a remote server when RPC is disabled

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

How do you drop a permanent table that has multiple prefixes on a remote server when rpc is disabled in SSMS v18 and above?

This is needed as part of a stored procedure.

First attempt:

```sql
drop table if exists [remote_server_name].[remote_db_name].dbo.[test123]
```

Error message:

> The object name 'remote_server_name.remote_db_name.dbo.test123' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

After googling the issue then tried the below;

Second attempt:

```sql
EXECUTE [remote_server_name].[remote_db_name].[dbo].[sp_executesql] N'DROP TABLE [dbo].[test123]'
```

Error message:

> Server 'remote_server_name' is not configured for RPC.

Third attempt:

```sql
drop table [remote_server_name].[remote_db_name].dbo.[test123]
```

Error message:

> The object name 'remote_server_name.remote_db_name.dbo.test123' contains more than the maximum number of prefixes. The maximum is 2.

Comment: Why not connect directly to the other server? *Why* do you want to do this via linked servers?

Comment: The Stored procedure is being recoded for a different server, but the table that is being dropped cannot yet be copied from the 'remote' server

Comment: What technique are you using to represent `remote_server_name`, exactly? Is this OPENROWSET, a Linked Server, or something else?

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server are you using? Are these all on-prem instances? Are there any Azure SQL or Azure SQL Managed Instance instances?

Comment: in this example let `remote_server_name` be = 'test_server' without the quotes - so its purely the name.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean by "RPC is disabled"? Does that include `EXEC [sql] AT`?

Comment: @unseen_rider You cannot parameterize identifiers in SQL (i.e. you cannot use a `varchar` parameter or variable to represent `remote_server_name`, but that's moot because `DROP TABLE` does not support non-local databases.

Comment: @dai edition is v18 Microsoft SQL Server Enterprise (64-bit). I don't know if the server is on-site or not. We do not believe it is Azure based

Comment: @dai a parameter or variable is not being used for the `remote_server_name`. I could equivalently say `servername1`.

Comment: _The Stored procedure is being recoded_ Honestly, what does that even mean? Sounds like consultant-speak for "we don't really know what we are going but are smart enough to fool people into thinking otherwise".

Comment: You're trying to call a procedure remotely and you can't change the linked server to support RPC (which stands for [remote procedure call](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2746/1186))? It's a simple yes/no in the config for the linked server. And you can dynamically call `sp_executesql` with a parameterized server name, e.g. `DECLARE @exec nvarchar(1000) = @server_name + N'.dbname.sys.sp_executesql'; EXEC @exec N'SELECT @@SERVERNAME, DB_NAME();';`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the premise of your entire question is wrong **as you cannot use `DROP TABLE` with non-local databases**. While this fact isn't explicitly stated in the documentation but can be inferred from the fact that the syntax for `DROP TABLE` specifically only supports these three variants:

```
DROP TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] database_name.schema_name.table_name;

DROP TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] schema_name.table_name;

DROP TABLE [ IF EXISTS ] table_name;
```

None of the above allow a SQL Server name to be used.

Curiously, the documentation *does* explicitly say that you cannot use 4-part names in Azure SQL (which to some people might imply that on-prem (non-Azure SQL) *does* support 4-part names, however the fact is neither edition of SQL Server support 4-part names, and therefore `DROP TABLE` cannot be used to drop remote tables:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

> Azure SQL Database supports the three-part name format database_name.`[schema_name].object_name` when the `database_name` is the current database or the `database_name` is `tempdb` and the `object_name` starts with `#`. Azure SQL Database does not support four-part names.

---

However, provided that you're using a Linked Server **with RPC enabled** then you *can* use `EXEC AT`. This approach does not work with other types of remote servers, such as `OPENROWSET` nor when "RPC: False" in Server Options.

```
EXEC ( 'DROP TABLE dbName.schema.tableName;' ) AT [LinkedServerName];
```

---

Otherwise, you cannot directly drop tables in a remote server from within a `PROCEDURE`.

A hack-ish approach might work whereby you use `xp_cmdshell` (which is also disabled by default) to run `sqlcmd.exe` (nee `osql.exe`) against an arbitrary SQL Server instance - though obviously you need to be ultra-careful with this approach (you'll also need Trusted Security (SSPI) working otherwise you'll need to hard-code a DDL-privileged user's password somewhere, which should be avoided in production systems).